# C# UserControl override font

Tags: c#, fonts, user-controls

I'm currently trying to override the font property of a customized UserControl in Visual Studio in C#. The property should just take the font of a label in the user control and ignore the font property of the UserControl.

Code:

```
[Bindable(true)]
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("Appearance")]
[Description("The font of the text in the control")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
public override Font Font
{
    get { return label1.Font; }
    set { label1.Font = value; }
}
```

But when I compiled the project source code and added the new UserControl to a form, Visual Studio crashes and restarts. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect **label1** is null

Comment: I checked the constructor. I don't think so. InitializeComponent() is executed. And I was able to override the Text property of the UserControl and return the Text property of the label.

Comment: Try add `if (value != null) { label1.Font = value; }`.

Comment: I tried it and VS crashed again, but you gave me a good hint.

Comment: I found out what went wrong. The answer is following.

Comment: VS is vulnerable to bugs with this site's name.  The Font property is an *ambient* property, a control normally uses its Parent's font.  So here the parent use the label's font and the label uses the parent font.  Goes on for a while, kaboom crash sad next.  Even if you set the label's Font property so it doesn't need its parent's font then you still have a problem because the user control needs its font first.  You have to set the label's font in the user control's constructor to avoid the crash.

Answer (score 5):

At first I want to say sorry that I answer my own question by myself after finding out what went wrong by myself. But I think that problem won't be rare, so here's the answer:

First of all when you create an own costomized UserControl keep in mind that first the UserControl you're working with is created and then the controls in the UserControl. When implementing a Font property in your UserControl the get-Accessor will be executed while InitializeComponent() is still not executed, which will lead to a crash of VS, when the Font property refers to another Font property in the way I did. The code should have looked that way:

```
private Font m_Font = DefaultFont;

[Bindable(true)]
[Browsable(true)]
[Category("Appearance")]
[Description("The font of the text in the control")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
public override Font Font
{
    get { return m_Font; }
    set
    {
        m_Font = value;
        label1.Font = m_Font;
    }
}
```

Comment: same fix applies if you are trying to refers the UserControl.ForeColor property to anotehr Color property